# how can add month without change number of days

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I want to create multiple dates .I get a specific date from the user and I want to add a month based on that date, but I do not want to change the number of days, for example.
User enter 2020-10-10
The next dates are the 10th of each month

Comment: What do you want to happen if they choose the 31st?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use DateTime.AddMonths(x) where x means the number of months you want to add (or to substract if x < 0).
You can as example create a for loop for x = 1 to 10 and then print these 10 dates.
Of course, it's never ruled out when adding exact one month that the day will change.